# How to encrypt to Django default pbkdf2_sha256 encryption?

Tags: django, passwords

I want to encrypt the user input password to compare with the original password in some view. I tried importing and apply `encrypt` method:

```
import passlib.hash.django_pbkdf2_sha256
```

But it doesn't have that module?

Comment: In the larger scope of things, the accepted answer is the right one. But as to why your import failed - django_pbkdf2_sha256 is a class, not a module, so you have to do `from passlib.hash import django_pbdfk2_sha256`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the `authenticate` method from `django.contrib.auth`:

```
test_user = authenticate(username=..., password=...)
```

If the credentials are valid, a new user will be returned, but this will not change the currently logged-in user. This will still work if some user uses a different encryption scheme, or if you are using custom authentication backends.

If for some reason you still need to reproduce Django's encryption, you can use `django.utils.crypto.pbkdf2`, but again, you will probably be better off using the higher level `check_password` function from `django.contrib.auth.hashers`:

```
check_password(new_password, encoded_password)
```

Comment: I am not trying to use it for authentication. There's a deactivate account feature. The account will be deactivated only when the user enters the correct password. So to compare the password I need to convert the text into the django encryption, compare them and if the two passwords are equal do the task.

Comment: I import from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher. What's the method to encrypt?

Comment: @user2032220 That is exactly what `authentication` does: it just checks that the provided username and password match what is in the database, and nothing else.

Comment: Apparently it does. I was thinking different thing. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password)

```
from models import User
new_user = User.objects.create(username='new_user', email='example@example.com')
new_user.set_password('newpassword')
```

Alternatively, you can use [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers)

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from models import User
first_pass = User.objects.all()[0].password.split('$')
hasher = first_pass[0]
salt = first_pass[1]  # grabbing salt from the first password of the database
make_password('newpassword', salt, hasher)
```

Comment: I had to use `salt = first_pass[2]` on line 5.  Probably the fields in the password string have changed since 2017.